# jdk 7 not active

Tags: macos, java

I just installed jdk 7 and I can't seem to be able to use it. I updated /Library/Java/Home/ to softlink to /Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home

I added /Library/Java/Home/bin to my path but java -version still returns

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home at 12:10AM 
➜ java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but the preferred way to find the current java home is to call /usr/libexec/java_home - my guess is that you need to update that or to understand how it works. It's still probably pointing to the older home.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to access the Java Preferences.app located in the utilities folder (you could also just search with spotlight). Here you will have to drag Java SE 7 to the very top.

As described by the Java Preferences:

> Java Applications and command line tools use this order to determine the first compatible version to use

Before and after:
[image]